# VBS crashing after VBA macro is done?

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to create a VBS script for my Excel macro, so users wont have to manually open Excel, nor see Excel, but only see the userform and the result.

Code for opening the Excel VBA works perfectly. However, when the Excel VBA macro finishes, the VBS code fails and leaves Excel open. Unaccessable for other users, thanks to the Excel One-User-policy.

Any Ideas?

My VBA code ends with the `Exit Sub` command.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "C:\Users\Flori\Desktop\Mail_Verteiler.xlsm!Modul1.Run"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Error put out is:

> Macro possibly not avaible or all macros have been deactivated.

Comment: You get that error first time when running or the subsequent times when Excel is left open? Also, is possible this is a typo? `Modul1` and not `Module1` ?

Comment: As I am running the german version, `Modul1` is correct.
Error happens, after the Macro itself is done. For example; (my macro runs a userform, which writes an email) I run the VBS, it opens the form, it writes the email, userform closes, VBS Error occurs. (on close of VBA macro)

Comment: *"When the Excel VBA macro finishes, the VBS code fails"* How exactly does the VBScript code fail? At which point in the code? Please show the full error message (including error code and line number).

Comment: Is this a synchronisation issue?  Does the VBS know to wait for Excel to finish.  It might need to pause.  So why not put all the code for closing Excel within Excel itself?  Would seem to be a more stable approach.

Comment: @Gareth Thanks for the idea. That solved my problem. 

AnsgarWiechers cant recreate the problem right now. Error Message was, that Windows wasnt able to find the Macro to be used (as programmed in the code)

Answer (score 0):

The Excel where there is your code, is it a `.xlsm` ? May be it's a `.xls` and it's why you get `Macro possibly not avaible or all macros have been deactivated`.

Comment: Yes, its a .xlsm

Answer (score 0):

@Gareth provided the final idea to shut down excel with VBA inside of the macro using the `Application.Quit`method.

That has resolved the issue.

Thanks everyone